# search a pattern in server log files on remote directory using java

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, open-source

I want to search a string pattern in some log files which are in remote directories and as a result, i want file name, line no/occurrence of string. I have an array of  file path, server address, credentials  and a string to be search . I have got some code for apache log parser from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/ParseanApachelogfilewithRegularExpressions.htm).  is there any way to parse file without installing anything on remote machine as a agent for running my parsing code ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: We could not possibly know that

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to "mimic" the famous `grep` program. "Googling" around I've found [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/nio/example/Grep.java) example from one of the  Oracle Examples. This class has the objective of:

> Search a list of files for lines that match a given regular-expression pattern.

But, as you can see this is from the 1.4.2 version of Java and you may have to update it yourself. Here's the class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.util.regex.*;


public class Grep {

    // Charset and decoder for ISO-8859-15
    private static Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-15");
    private static CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();

    // Pattern used to parse lines
    private static Pattern linePattern = Pattern.compile(".*\r?\n");

    // The input pattern that we're looking for
    private static Pattern pattern;

    // Compile the pattern from the command line
    //
    private static void compile(String pat) {

        try {
            pattern = Pattern.compile(pat);
        } catch (PatternSyntaxException x) {
            System.err.println(x.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

        // Use the linePattern to break the given CharBuffer into lines, applying
        // the input pattern to each line to see if we have a match
        //
        private static void grep(File f, CharBuffer cb) {
        Matcher lm = linePattern.matcher(cb);   // Line matcher
        Matcher pm = null;          // Pattern matcher
        int lines = 0;
        while (lm.find()) {
            lines++;
            CharSequence cs = lm.group();   // The current line
            if (pm == null)
            pm = pattern.matcher(cs);
            else
            pm.reset(cs);
            if (pm.find())
            System.out.print(f + ":" + lines + ":" + cs);
            if (lm.end() == cb.limit())
            break;
            }
        }

        // Search for occurrences of the input pattern in the given file
        //
        private static void grep(File f) throws IOException {

        // Open the file and then get a channel from the stream
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        FileChannel fc = fis.getChannel();

        // Get the file's size and then map it into memory
        int sz = (int)fc.size();
        MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, sz);

        // Decode the file into a char buffer
        CharBuffer cb = decoder.decode(bb);

        // Perform the search
        grep(f, cb);

        // Close the channel and the stream
        fc.close();
        }
```

For using it to grep all files in a directory you could use:

```
public void listFilesInDirectory(File dir) {
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        for (File f : files) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
            listFilesInDirectory(f);
         }
         else
             Grep.grep(f);
         }
    }
}
```

I Hope it helped. Cheers